# Regex, Remove function in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get the function DoDialogwizardWithArguments that is inside a string using Regex:

string:

```
var a = 1 + 2;DoDialogWizardWithArguments('CopyGroup', '&act=enviarcliente', 96487, (Q.getBody().$.innerWidth()/4)*3, Q.getBody().$.innerHeight(), new Function("if(localStorage.getItem('atualizaPgsParaCli')){{Q.window.close();Q.window.proxy.reload();}}localStorage.removeItem('atualizaPgsParaCli');return true;"), false);p = q.getBOdy();
```

actual Regex (pattern):

```
DoDialogWizardWithArguments\((.*\$?)\)
```

Result expected:

```
DoDialogWizardWithArguments('CopyGroup', '&act=enviarcliente', 96487, (Q.getBody().$.innerWidth()/4)*3, Q.getBody().$.innerHeight(), new Function("if(localStorage.getItem('atualizaPgsParaCli')){{Q.window.close();Q.window.proxy.reload();}}localStorage.removeItem('atualizaPgsParaCli');return true;"), false)
```

The problem:

If there's another parentheses ")" that is not the parentheses of DoDialogWizardWithArguments function the Regex is getting this too.

How can i get only the function with his open and close parentheses.

If Regex is not possible, whats the better option?

Example regex link:https://regex101.com/r/kP2bQ4/1

Comment: I don't know if you are going to be able to match this using a regular expression as there doesn't seem to be any way to indicate when it ends (at least not unless you set your end condition to match until it sees a `p = q.getBOdy();`,which I'm not sure would work for you.

Comment: yes, it can be a lot of things after the function, the user can create the command,  i have to extract only the function.

Comment: You want to scan a string and get the output: DoDialogWizardWithArguments("stuff", "stuff", .. ... ); ??
If so, just do:

"DoDialogWizardWithArguments([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,([^,]*),.+);" and this sould detect your sentence, but not if it has valid inputs. Do you want to check the function is ('this', 'this', 1234, (something), true|false); ?
If you just want to get DoDialogWizardWithArguments(...); use what I commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one as regex: https://regex101.com/r/kP2bQ4/2

```
DoDialogWizardWithArguments\(((?:[^()]|\((?1)\))*+)\)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably try to simplify it like this:

```
var str = @"var a = 1 + 2;DoDialogWizardWithArguments('CopyGroup', '&act=enviarcliente', 96487, (Q.getBody().$.innerWidth()/4)*3, Q.getBody().$.innerHeight(), new Function("if(localStorage.getItem('atualizaPgsParaCli')){{Q.window.close();Q.window.proxy.reload();}}localStorage.removeItem('atualizaPgsParaCli');return true;"), false);p = q.getBOdy();"
var lines = str.Split(';');
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    if(line.Contains("DoDialogWizardWithArguments")){
        int startPos = line.IndexOf("(");
        int endPos = line.IndexOf(")");        
        return line.Substring(startPos+1, endPos - startPos - 1);
    }
}
return "Not found";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to detect if DoDialogWizardWithArguments was correctly written but just the function itself, try with "DoDialogWizardWithArguments([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,([^,]*),.+);".
Example:

```
String src = @"xdasadsdDoDialogWizardWithArguments('CopyGroup', '&act=enviarcliente', 96487, (Q.getBody().$.innerWidth()/4)*3, Q.getBody().$.innerHeight(), new Function(" + "\""
                + "if(localStorage.getItem('atualizaPgsParaCli')){{Q.window.close();Q.window.proxy.reload();}}localStorage.removeItem('atualizaPgsParaCli');return true;"
                + "\"" + "), false);p"; //An example of what you asked for

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"DoDialogWizardWithArguments([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,([^,]*),.+);"); //This is your function
MessageBox.Show(r.Match(src).Value);
if (r.IsMatch(src))
    MessageBox.Show("Yeah, it's DoDialog");

else MessageBox.Show("Nope, Nope, Nope");
```